# How to resolove ReactJS Background Image not working

Tags: reactjs

Hello so I am working on a Tinder clone like app so I want to add an image to the card using the inline styling with the JSX so that I can have access to the object which has the peoples images however it does not render that image but it renders the names which by my understanding if it can render the name it should be able to render the image can I please get help.

**Code Below: TinderCards component**

```
    const TinderCards = () =>{

    const [people, setPeople] = useState([

        {
            name: 'Beyonce',
            url: 'https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.guim.co.uk%2Fimg%2Fmedia%2Fb7d881ef7d3fbddf351d3b8b01e13553c644d669%2F0_0_2703_2270%2Fmaster%2F2703.jpg%3Fwidth%3D700%26quality%3D85%26auto%3Dformat%26fit%3Dmax%26s%3Db41f0033c8595a6c348a5e7d5856a161&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.theguardian.com%2Flifeandstyle%2F2018%2Faug%2F10%2Fmeaning-beyonce-dispatch-inside-the-beyhive&tbnid=eAPsSE97D5rVqM&vet=12ahUKEwjeuMjk65XrAhWBjxoKHbApBp8QMygAegUIARDIAQ..i&docid=BO1VGL_FO__UzM&w=700&h=588&q=Picture%20of%20Beyonce&client=firefox-b-d&ved=2ahUKEwjeuMjk65XrAhWBjxoKHbApBp8QMygAegUIARDIAQ'
        },
        {
            name: 'Jay Z',
            url: 'https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Ftownsquare.media%2Fsite%2F812%2Ffiles%2F2019%2F11%2Fjay-z.jpg%3Fw%3D980%26q%3D75&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxlmag.com%2Fjay-z-ahmaud-arbery-lawyer-private-jet-court%2F&tbnid=MMF2ad9EJS69wM&vet=12ahUKEwiI8aX565XrAhUC0xoKHcmbBZIQMygCegUIARDBAQ..i&docid=1Kch3x6EX1i1pM&w=980&h=653&q=Picture%20of%20Jay%20z&client=firefox-b-d&ved=2ahUKEwiI8aX565XrAhUC0xoKHcmbBZIQMygCegUIARDBAQ'
        }
    ]);

    return(

        <div style={style}>

            <div className="tinder-card__container">

                {people.map((person) => {

                    return( 

                    <TinderCard className="swipe"
                        key={person.name}
                        preventSwipe={['up', 'down']}>

                        <div 
                         style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${person.url})` }}
                         className="card">


                         <h3>{person.name}</h3>
                 
                        </div> 
                     </TinderCard>
            
                     )
                
     
        
        
            </div>
        
        </div>

    )
}

export default TinderCards;
```

**The Image is the output that I am getting i.e No Image being rendered**

[image]

Comment: Set the width and height for the image

Comment: Hey so I am failing to understand how I am going to pull it via css because I am getting the Image directly from the object and I had made the styling for the card and all so that the contents are centered...

Comment: just remove the $ sign from the image url...`${person.url}`

Comment: Won't it take ```{person.url}``` as a string now and it would not render that object url?

Comment: did your try that?

Comment: Yes, I just did and automatically took it like string, syntax highlighting showed that too

Comment: Oh sorry those were back-ticks my bad... did you checked URL render correctly?

Comment: Lemme try that, to make thing easy would it be possible for me to use local file images and how can I do that?

Comment: And yes the was a problem with the Image link but how can I use my local file images?

Comment: try this and let me know  `url("${person.url}")`

Comment: The other first way works I just did not have the correct Image link, but can you teach me how I can my local image files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include local images (**as you stated in comments**) just use `require` function.

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(require("images/Beyonce.png"))` }} className="card">
```

or

```
import BeyonceImg from './your_dir_path/images/Beyonce.png';

<div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${BeyonceImg})` }} className="card">
```